# String in class doesn't name a type

Tags: c++, class, oop, codeblocks, physics

Today I have tried to make a class named calculator, for a physics project and as the name suggests, my class would just do calculations. Being a program for physics, it's expected to need calculus formulas; and they would be calculated using parameterized functions, returning a string consisting of a double and the measuring unit like this: `177 J/Kg*K`

Now, let's get to the problem:

So i have tested my functions, and after that I decided to make it into Object Oriented Programming as it would make things a little bit simpler for me, at least...
After making the class, I got an error saying that

> "string" in "class Calculator" doesn't define a type

Here is the code:

**Calculator.h**

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Calculator{
private:

public:
    Calculator();
    string capCalorica(double cReceived, double varTemp);
    string caldSpecifica(double cReceived, double varTemp, double mass);
};

#endif // CALCULATOR_H
```

**Calculator.cpp**

```
#include "Calculator.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

Calculator::Calculator(){
    cout<<"Calculus Module Initialized!"<<endl;
    Sleep(2000);
    system("cls");
}

Calculator::string capCalorica(double cReceived, double varTemp)){
    stringstream sstr;
    double result = cReceived/varTemp;

    sstr<<result<<" J/Kg";

    return sstr.str();
}

Calculator::string caldSpecific(double cReceived, double mass, double varTemp){
    stringstream sstm;
    double result = cReceived/(mass*varTemp);

    sstm<<result<<" J/Kg*K";

    return sstm.str();
}
```

The error is in the cpp file, wherever i defined a string returning function

Comment: nowhere in Calculator.h do you `#include <string>`.

Comment: add `#include<string>` in the header file.

Comment: Never write a *using-directive* at file scope in a header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
Calculator::string capCalorica(double cReceived, double varTemp)){
...
}
```

to

```
std::string Calculator::capCalorica(double cReceived, double varTemp)){
...}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration `string capCalorica(double cReceived, double varTemp);` in the header file uses `string` as a type, yet this type is not known at this point. You simply forgot to `#include<string>` in the header file.

Comment: #ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Calculator{
private:

public:
    Calculator();
    string capCalorica(double cPrimit, double varTemp);
    string caldSpecifica(double cPrimit, double varTemp, double masa);
};

#endif // CALCULATOR_H





Did nothing.....

Comment: @Zentrix, The code in your comment [compiles here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6KGjdI).

Comment: yes, no problem in the header, that's right! 
I said that the IDE signals an error `Calculator::string capCalorica(double cReceived, double varTemp)` here and `Calculator::string caldSpecifica(double cReceived, double mass, double varTemp)` here

Comment: Note that `Calculator::string` is something different than `std::string`. Your IDE probably assumes an `Calculator::string` (which is not defined then), as you forgot to include a header defining `string` in the namespace `std` (as used then in the cpp-file)

Comment: yes, but i used USING NAMESPACE STD;  at the top of the CPP file, so what should be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that there is NO `Calculator::string`.

Comment: `using` is a shortcut that allows you to write `string` instead of `std::string`, yet it does not define the type `string`; for that, you need the #include<string> first.

Comment: @Swordfish yes, you are right... the problem was the wording. i should have written `string Calculator::caldSpecifica` . Thanks for waking me up, mates!

Comment: @Zentrix a note about `using namespace std;`. It can be more trouble than it's worth. More on that here: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). As noted in the comments under the question, using it without scoping it in a header is extremely frowned on as turns the header into a boobytrap for anyone who wrote their code expecting proper namespace behaviour and includes the header.